# How to upload large file(s) on FTP server using php?

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

```
$ftp_server = 'ftp.abc.com';
$remote_file = "myvideo.avi";  // file size 210MB
$file = "myvideo.avi";        // file size 210MB
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);  // set up basic connection

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'faraz@abc.com', 'password');

ftp_pasv($conn_id, true); // turn passive mode on
// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
     echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
} else {
     echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
}
    // close the connection
    ftp_close($conn_id);

i already edit php.in for
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
```

above snippet working on all types of file(s) upload, 
    but when am trying to upload a large size file then it upload on server but size varies after uploading.
    A video file size-210MB on local-machine 
    but after upload, it displayed file size 328KB on FTP-server. 
    i have no idea where do i check, if someone has suggestion then i appreciates

Comment: ok i'll. but i have accepted all.

Comment: No, you probably just upvoted answers but not accepted them. See the my link in the previous comment for how to do it. Oh, and you shouldn't use `FTP_ASCII` at all. Nowadays there is usually no good reason to use it and for binary files it will even break them!

Comment: oohh i see, i will do it now every time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `FTP_BINARY` instead of `FTP_ASCII`. The latter might stop at the first NUL byte.

Besides that, there is no good reason to use ascii mode nowadays, even for ascii files. The **only** case where it's important if you have cgi scripts containing a shebang line that have windows linebreaks locally.

Comment: how can i check ftp server name is valid or not?