# How to Check Upload File Through FTP in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Can Aanybody Help Me ! I want to do that some files (like pdf or .xls or .doc) upload through FTP in Project's user panel when user run our panel then automatic inform to user that these files uploaded by you. is it Possible? if yes then help me.

Thanks
Sonu

Comment: did you searched on google ? what have you tried ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to upload large file(s) on FTP server using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10153502/how-to-upload-large-files-on-ftp-server-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('ftp');

$config['hostname'] = 'ftp.example.com';
$config['username'] = 'your-username';
$config['password'] = 'your-password';
$config['debug']    = TRUE;

$this->ftp->connect($config);

$this->ftp->upload('/local/path/to/myfile.html', '/public_html/myfile.html', 'ascii', 0775);

$this->ftp->close();
```

Each time you connect to FTP log to a table what are the files uploaded and what time, based on this information update you the user the following files are uploaded.

Reference: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/ftp.html

Comment: thanks for reply. I don't want to upload file file using Codeigniter i just want to know which file recently uploaded by FTP that's all Only List of Recently Uploaded Files Path Uploaded by FTP